# Filter array based on particular key in typescript or react native?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am handling json structure, But I want to filter and create separate arrays based on particular key.

Actual JSON:

```
data: {
      message: 'Customer Transaction',
      errorCode: null,
      data: [
        {
          fields: 'Expected number of transaction per quarter',
          attributeValue: '1 to 25',
          attributeValueCode:"7",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Expected number of transaction per quarter',
          attributeValue: '26 to 50',
          attributeValueCode:"8",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Expected number of transaction per quarter',
          attributeValue: 'Greater than 50',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Monthly Cash Deposit',
          attributeValue: 'Nil',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Monthly Cash Deposit',
          attributeValue: '<2 Lacs',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Monthly Cash Deposit',
          attributeValue: '2 - 10 Lacs',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Monthly Cash Withdrawal',
          attributeValue: 'Nil',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Monthly Cash Withdrawal',
          attributeValue: '<2 Lacs',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
        {
          fields: 'Monthly Cash Withdrawal',
          attributeValue: '2 - 10 Lacs',
          attributeValueCode:"3",
        },
      ],
    },
```

Expected JSON After manipulation:

```
{"metaData":{
    "Expected number of transaction per quarter": ['1 to 25','26 to 50', 'Greater than 50'],
    "Monthly Cash Deposit": ['Nil','<2 Lacs','2 - 10 Lacs'],
    "Monthly Cash Withdrawal": ['Nil','<2 Lacs','2 - 10 Lacs']
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't include the `attributeValueCode` in the output?

Comment: @blaumeise20 Thanks for the comment. Actually I don't want to add attributeValueCode. Simply Based on fields I want to add attributeValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and set `fields` as the key and push `attributeValue` to the array

```js
data.data.reduce(
  (acc, { fields, attributeValue }) => {
    if (!acc.metaData[fields]) acc.metaData[fields] = []

    acc.metaData[fields].push(attributeValue)

    return acc
  },
  { metaData: {} },
)
```